# wpf style cascade

Tags: wpf, styles

Can you declare a style in/for a container (Grid, Canvas, etc) that will cascade to contained elements of other types?

For Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Declare some style with target type of Label/>
    <label Name="ElementIwantStyleAppliedTo1" Content="Foo"/>
    <StackPanel>
         <label Name="ElementIwantStyleAppliedTo2" Content="Foo"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the basics!

use Resource property of the container control.

```
<Grid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
     </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```